re: psql running on a ssh server
(ubuntu terminal, and the server is using bash)
i have installed psql in a ssh server inside conda env as I don't have sudo privileges, so I successfully installed the psql have tables inside it everything. also for other users of the same server who wants to access the psql db I just made a script file which will direct them to the miniconda--->>> then starts the server ->>>> then connects to psql. but the other user apart from me whoever is using the script file to connect to db is getting a seg core dumped error just like this
4003 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) psql -U client -d project

and when I checked the log file it tells
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.

my guess is since I myself the owner for the directory who created the db and started the server and letting others to use, while the others using access_tables.sh script which also has a line of code which will start the psql server again by the user apart from the owner who owns the data directory this server is getting crashed and seg fault error is happening.
